# Error while creating Pivot Table automatically

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have created a macro to create a table with some values via Index matches and general calculations. This table is located on the range("AA1:BA"&LastRow) --> I am writing LastRow because the lastrow changes daily. I want to create a pivot table which will be located in the cell(9,1) and will have as a source the initial table that I created.. I built the code that you see below, but it gives me an error saying that the PivotTable field name is not valid on the line :

```
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange).CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), TableName:="PivotTable")
```

The entire code related to the Pivot Table is below.

```
   Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set PSheet = Worksheets("Budget_Report")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("Budget_Report")

LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 27).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 27).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(9, 1), TableName:="PivotTable")

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("T-Lane")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
.Subtotals(1) = True
.Subtotals(1) = False
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Monthly Cost FCST")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 1
.Function = xlSum
.Name = "Monthly Cost Forecast"
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Monthly Vol FCST")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 2
.Function = xlSum
.Name = "Monthly Vol Forecast"
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Monthly $/SU FCST")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 3
.Function = xlSum
.Name = "Monthly $/SU Forecast"
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Monthly Cost Actuals")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 4
.Function = xlSum
.Name = "Monthly Cost Actual"
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Monthly Vol Actuals")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 5
.Function = xlSum
.Name = "Monthly Vol Actual"
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Monthly $/SU Actuals")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 6
.Function = xlSum
.Name = "Monthly $/SU Actual"
End With
```

The recorded macro that builds the Pivot Table is provided below (it has specific range not lastrow and lastcolumn of course)

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="Budget_Report!R1C27:R279C53", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Budget_Report!R9C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=6
Sheets("Budget_Report").Cells(9, 1).Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("T-Lane")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Monthly Cost FCST"), "Monthly Cost Forecast", xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Monthly Vol FCST"), "Monthly Vol Forecast", xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Monthly $/SU FCST"), "Monthly $/SU Forecast", xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Monthly Cost Actuals"), "Monthly Cost Actual", xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Monthly Vol Actuals"), "Monthly Vol Actual", xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Monthly $/SU Actuals"), "Monthly $/SU Actual", xlSum

ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False
```

Comment: what would be the field names of the pivot table if there was no error?

Comment: hmm I am sorry jsotola but I dont really understand the question.. I am not very experienced with Pivot Tables so I cannot really answer the question :( I just saw the code online and tried to implement it for my macro .

Comment: do you actually have data that can be fed into a pivot table? ... if you do, then create the pivot table manually. excel should complain about the field name and it may point you to the problem.

Comment: I just created the pivot table manually and it has no issue.. Could it be because I am naming the Pivot Table in the line where I set the PTable?

Comment: create the pivot table again, but this time start the macro recorder before you do the creation. then check the resulting code

Comment: Ok I did it.. But the issue is that now it does not use lastrow and lastcolumn so, if the range changes, it wont work.. And it looks really different than the one I posted because it does not have any dims etc..

Comment: Try replacing `Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(9, 1), TableName:="PivotTable")` 
with `Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(9, 1))` and also replace any instance of `With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable")` to `With PTable`

Comment: again it says that the PivotTable  field name is not valid. If you are changing the name of a PivotTable field, you must type a new name for the field.

Comment: My suggested revision still provides the new names. So for instance this: `With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("T-Lane")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
.Subtotals(1) = True
.Subtotals(1) = False
End With` ...becomes this: `With PTable.PivotFields("T-Lane")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
.Subtotals(1) = True
.Subtotals(1) = False
End With`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting the `PRange` you can use `Cells.SpecialCells` method to set your range even though you don't always know what that end address will be as long as you're sure you won't have extra data somewhere below/beyond your target range.

It would look something like this:

```
Set PRange = DSheet.Range(DSheet.Cells(1, 27), DSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
```

Also, it is a matter of personal style, but I find that nesting `With` blocks sometimes results in more readable code. Eg:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    With .PivotFields("Field 1")
        .Caption = "My first field"
        .Function = xlSum
    End With
    With .PivotFields("Field 2")
        .Caption = "My second field"
        .Function = xlMax
    End With
End With
```

etc.

The final product looks something like this:

```
Dim DSheet As Worksheet  ', PSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache, PTable As PivotTable, PRange As Range
'Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long

'Application.DisplayAlerts = False   ' This is redundant since you're setting it to true below.
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
'Set PSheet = Worksheets("Budget_Report") '
Set DSheet = Worksheets("Budget_Report") ' These two are Redundant - I am using only DSheet.

'LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 27).End(xlUp).Row
'LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set PRange = DSheet.Range(Cells(1, 27),Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))

Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=DSheet.Cells(9, 1), TableName:="PivotTable")

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable")
 With .PivotFields("T-Lane")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
    .Subtotals(1) = True   ' You're resetting this value in the next     line, you can probably remove it.
    .Subtotals(1) = False
 End With

With .PivotFields("Monthly Cost FCST")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 1
.Function = xlSum
.Caption = "Monthly Cost Forecast" 'You want .Caption here, not .Name
End With

With .PivotFields("Monthly Vol FCST")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 2
.Function = xlSum
.Caption = "Monthly Vol Forecast"
End With

With .PivotFields("Monthly $/SU FCST")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 3
.Function = xlSum
.Caption = "Monthly $/SU Forecast"
End With

With .PivotFields("Monthly Cost Actuals")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 4
.Function = xlSum
.Caption = "Monthly Cost Actual"
End With

With .PivotFields("Monthly Vol Actuals")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 5
.Function = xlSum
.Caption = "Monthly Vol Actual"
End With

With .PivotFields("Monthly $/SU Actuals")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 6
.Function = xlSum
.Caption = "Monthly $/SU Actual"
End With

End With
```

Comment: Happy to hear it worked for you. Beware, the PivotCaches.Create article at MSDN indicates _When passing a Range, it is recommended to either use a string to specify the workbook, worksheet, and cell range, or set up a named range and pass the name as a string. Passing a Range object may cause "type mismatch" errors unexpectedly._  [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pivotcaches-create-method-excel)

Comment: sorry to bother you again buddy.. If I want to add a second table in the same sheet with the same sourcedata (but with different displaying data of course) what should I change in the code?? I set a new PTable2 and I just changed the name of the pivottable as PivotTable2 and it says that it cannot overwrite a pivot table

Comment: You also need to specify a new place to put it - you can't have one pivottable over the top of another. `TableDestination:=...`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you try to create the same table twice:

```
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange).CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), TableName:="PivotTable")
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(9, 1), TableName:="PivotTable")
```

Just split it in two:

```
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(9, 1), TableName:="PivotTable")
```

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas The line with `Set PTable...` is definitely correct. So either you already have a pivot table with that name, something is wrong with the destination or `PivotCache` was not created correctly.

Comment: Its actually the only Pivot Table I have on this workbook! could it be that I create the Pivot Table in the same sheet with the data that it uses as source?

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas It might be that you are trying to write the pivot table to an occupied range. Step into code after `Set PCache` and type in immediate window `?PCache.SourceData` and check if the Cache was created correctly

Comment: It tells me object required

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas then it is likely that your `PivotCache` is not created correctly. Check that `ActiveWorkbook` is the same workbook that has your data in `PRange`.

Comment: Well it is actually the same! I will upload the code as it is after what you told me to change and below, I will upload the recorded code for creating the pivot table.. their difference is that the recorded one has specific range while the other one has lastrow and lastcolumn.. maybe this way you can see something that I dont!

Answer (score 0):

Assign to PCache only Cache:

```
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)
```

Comment: It gives an automation error on the line where I set the PTable